# State in Android Compose vs XML / imperative framework

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am going through the Compose pathway and I keep seeing all of this emphasis on state hoisting. Is this in some way more relevant in the new Compose framework as compared to the old paradigm? It seems like it is just a good programming technique in general. I am worried I am missing a particular advantage in the Composable system.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of an `Activity` or a `Fragment` they are nearly identical. A stream of states come in and the `Activity` or `Fragment` needs to react to the changes by updating its content.

In Compose, however, the composables are themselves tiny fragments of UI all the way down, so to speak. In Compose you can arbitrarily break a UI into smaller and smaller pieces that each react to state changes. It is in this decomposition (so to speak) that state hoisting becomes important and allows these smaller UI pieces to be reusable. Even when you use a `Text` or a `Button` they are just composable functions that layout and draw text or map user input to click events, etc.

If state is already in the UI model then it is already hoisted. No additional hoisting is necessary. State hoisting is only important if the composable has its own model of information.  The `TextField`, for example, takes its state as a parameter instead of creating and holding it internally. This allows the state to be held directly in the UI model instead of needing to be synchronized with it. The model can decide if an when the state changes, the `TextField` just requests the state to change, it doesn't control it. Traditionally, a `TextField` would have it own internal model of the text and just send out `onChange` notifications when the value changed. This means there are at least two models of the value of the field, one held by the control and one held by the application model. Synchronizing these can be tricky.

Allowing hoisting of composable state allows there to be a single source of truth, the application model, instead of several states all needing to be synchronized to a single value. Compose does not dictate what the model is or how it is stored, it just needs to know when the value changes so it knows when to update the UI.